# Como trabalhar com response do Alamofire em Swift 4?

Tags: swift, alamofire

Possuo a seguinte request que me retorna um json nao consigo pegar as ulrs de live

```
Alamofire.request(urlRequest).validate().responseJSON { response in
                print(response.data)

                do {
                    if let data = response.data,
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
                        let live = json["live"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                        for live in live {
                            if let livesUrl = live["live"] as? String {
                                self.urlLive.append(liveUrl)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
                }
                print(self.urlLive)
            }
```

**JSON QUE A REQUEST ME RETORNA**

> [
>       {
>           "id": "1",
>           "description": "TESTE 1",
>           "live": "https://.....",
>           "thumb": "https://.....",
>           "online": true
>       },
>       {
>           "id": "2",
>           "description": "TESTE 2",
>           "live": "https://.....",
>           "thumb": "https://.....",
>           "online": true
>       }]

Comment: Pq voce nao usa Codable protocol em vez de parse manualmente o seu JSON?

Comment: tem um exemplo de como utilizar?

Answer (score -1):

No retorno da função `.responseJSON` a resposta já está serializada. Você só precisa fazer:

```
Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
    if let array = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
        for item in array {
            let description = item["live"] as? String
            print(description)
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling